# What is the expected behavior of L2 systems under a chainsplit?

Tags: blockchain-fork, layer-2, rollups

Assuming that there is both a optimistic rollup L2 and a zkrollup L2 system functioning nominally (i.e. they are both publishing their rollups to L1).

Assume that a chain split happens at block 10000 resulting in chain ethA and ethB

Assume that all L2 chains choose chain ethA.

Given that the L2 system is functioning nominally on ethA it should be trivial for users to recover their funds on L1.

How do the users recover their funds on the ethB side of the chain split?